# Famous projects using Scrum

Tags: scrum

As some of you know now, I'm trying to introduce Scrum in our company. Our CEO asked me if famous projects and/or big companies used the method. I found some companies, that's easy (Google, Yahoo, Microsoft, Facebook, Adobe, Nokia, Siemens, BBC, CNN, General Electric, Bank of America, Novell, Unisys...). Google maintains a list of companies using Scrum [here](http://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=t9L4o6JXfQTa8I4DKkvka5g#gid=1). But which famous projects use Scrum? That's not so easy. Do you know some?

Comment: What is the specific problem that you are facing?  This seems a lot like a poll or list type question where every single answer can be a correct answer. I'm strongly considering closing this question as the [FAQ](http://pm.stackexchange.com/faq) very explicitly states that questions like this are off-topic, where every answer is equally valid, and where there is no actual problem to be solved. (See the section "What kind of questions should I *not* ask here?"). If you can edit the question so that it meets the guidelines, then perhaps we can keep it open/reopen it.  Thanks Traroth!

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was clear from the question. The purpose is to demonstrate that Scrum is a valuable method by giving our CEO examples of famous successful projects using it, which he explicitly asked for. As I was not able to find anything of interest by simply googling it, I asked here.

Comment: I agree that the question has a wrong format for our site, but I'm very interested to see answers, since the subject is interesting. Maybe we can change question format somehow?

Comment: I think that as long as we're vigilant and watch these questions to make sure the answers are good quality I think it's fine.  We can convert to community wiki too if it gets too many one liner answers.

Comment: I had myself a Scrum issue. That interested many members of our community. I think that this question helps us have a balanced view ot the Scrum model.

Comment: I'm not sure that question is still of any interest. Nowadays, chances are most of development teams are using Scrum one way or another. I don't really know what to do with it, though. SE doesn't recommend to delete questions with answers, so I will just let the question be for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BBC iPlayer team I believe used Scrum.  iirc they're doing more Kanban type stuff now but it's a good tangible project to talk about.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely take a look at the salesforce.com story - it's a classic.  You can Google it or read the whitepaper here:

*[Transforming Your Organization to Agile: The inside story of salesforce.com’s transformation from waterfall to agile](https://web.archive.org/web/20110429103410/http://www.ca.com/Files/WhitePapers/wp-agile-development_239775.pdf)*

From the whitepaper:

> By 2006, the last of the company’s
>   “pre-agile” days, salesforce.com had
>   gone from four seasonal releases per
>   year down to just one, which goes
>   against the very grain of cloud
>   computing. That release, which took
>   about 15 months to complete, was a key
>   indicator that the company needed to
>   make a radical change in its
>   development methodology. Since our
>   move to agile, each successive major
>   release has been deployed on the exact
>   day it was scheduled.

Answer (score 5):

I found an article on scrumalliance.org about Adobe using Scrum:

[Scrum @ Adobe - including downloadable slides (56 pages, 5MB)](https://web.archive.org/web/20121031011719/http://www.scrumalliance.org/resources/612)

They use it in all of their developments, now, and began with Adobe Lifecycle, Adobe Soundbooth and Adobe Audition.

Answer (score 2):

One of my favorite Agile companies is Menlo Innovations out of Ann Arbor.  They are not Scrum per se but XP.

Bear in mind that many of the early adopters have evolved from Scrum through continuous improvement.

The trap with seeking out success stories is they take a while to get published and if you expect to see a success story before putting your feet in the water you are already a quantum leap behind.  More here
[don't be a blockbuster](https://web.archive.org/web/20121026071308/http://www.rallydev.com/agileblog/2010/10/dont-be-a-blockbuster/)

Answer (score 2):

Street Fighter IV heres the link: [street fighter game built using agile and scrum](https://web.archive.org/web/20160927133125/http://agilescout.com/street-fighter-game-built-using-agile-and-scrum/)

and the games by Wooga: [monsters built using kanban](https://web.archive.org/web/20160831163251/http://agilescout.com/monsters-built-using-kanban/)

Answer (score 1):

The AdWords project at Google uses Scrum

Comment: Do you have any references about that?

Comment: you can find a video about it on youtube